# Named URN for SHA1withECDSA signature algorithm

Tags: cryptography, ecdsa

The URN form ECDSA signature algorithm is 
    `urn:nist-gov:ecdsa`.

But I am not able to find a named URN for algorithm SHA1withECDSA.

Up to now I've found the xmldsig URL for SHA1withECDSA: 
    http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha1

And I have the option to generate the URN with its OID, according to RFC3061: 
urn:oid:1.2.840.10045.4.1

I could even create my own version of its URN as something like urn:nist-gov:ecdsa-sha1

But, is it a named standard URN for signature algorithm SHA1withECDSA ?

Comment: I can't validate it but given the timeframe for ECDSA  it's possible that SHA-1 is implied by `urn:nist-gov:ecdsa` (I found some references where DSA and ECDSA do not take any parameter, and they need a hash to function; furthermore, SHA-1 was the only approved hash for quite some time). Better ask at crypto.stackexchange.com though.

Comment: Ok. I've asked it in crypto.stackexchange.com: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45126/urn-for-ecdsa-signature-algorithms-including-hash-algorithm